# Nginx configuration for matching wildcard server_name to specific Symfony route

Tags: nginx, rewrite, symfony

i have a Symfony 5 application at domain.tld with this basic nginx configuration:

```
map "$http_cloudfront_forwarded_proto:$http_x_forwarded_proto" $cloudfront_proto {
    default "http";
    "~https" "https";
}

server {
    server_name domain.tld;
    listen 80 backlog=65535;

    root /var/www/project/public;

    client_max_body_size 500M;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # optionally disable falling back to PHP script for the asset directories;
    # nginx will return a 404 error when files are not found instead of passing the
    # request to Symfony (improves performance but Symfony's 404 page is not displayed)
    # location /bundles {
    #     try_files $uri =404;
    # }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        # optionally set the value of the environment variables used in the application
        # fastcgi_param APP_ENV prod;
        # fastcgi_param APP_SECRET <app-secret-id>;
        # fastcgi_param DATABASE_URL "mysql://db_user:db_pass@host:3306/db_name";
        fastcgi_param HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO $cloudfront_proto;

        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/index.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

My use case :

I have severals routes:

```
/site/{siteUrl}
/site/{siteUrl}/*
/site/{siteUrl}/*/*
...
```

like :

- https://www.domain.tld/site/prefix.domainA.tld
- https://www.domain.tld/site/prefix.domainB.tld/category-name
- https://www.domain.tld/site/prefix.domainC.tld/category-name/section-name

I want to access to this routes with an url like

- https://prefix.domainA.tld
- https://prefix.domainB.tld/category-name
- https://prefix.domainC.tld/category-name/section-name

I don"t want a redirection, but a rewrite rule for alls urls begin with prefix.domain.tld point to /site/prefix.domain.tld urls and all other statics assets urls like prefix.domain.tld/build/css/custom.css works.

I try to add a new server block with this add:

```
server {
    server_name prefix.*;
    root /var/www/project/public;
    listen 80;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    location = / {
        rewrite ^ /index.php/site/$host break;
    }

...
```

But it didn't work at all...

Can you help me ? :D

Thanks

Comment: What exactly did you do when "it didn't work at all..."? What request did you make? What was the exact response?

Comment: Hello Tero. When I try https://prefix.domainA.tld a got a 404 Not Found nginx error